# How can I prove by contradiction that there is no real number such that $q^2 = -1$

Tags: real-numbers

How can I prove by contradiction that there is no real number such that $q^2 = -1$.

You would have to assume that there exists a $q$ that satisfies $q^2 = -1$.

But I can´t understand how I am supposed to prove this.

Do I have to first assume that $q$ is positive, and make it such that $q = -1/q >0$.

I cannot see how this contradicts my assumption that there exists a real number which satisfies $q^2 = -1$

Comment: The square of **every** natural, rational, real number is $\ge 0$.

Comment: Why not distinguishing the three cases $q>0$ , $q<0$ , $q=0$ to show $q^2\ge 0$ for every real $q$ which is the desired contradiction ?

Comment: A "good" proof requires some work... You have to start from the [Axioms for the real numbers](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA62). Then prove *trichotomy* and then [prove that "if $a \ne 0$, then $a^2 > 0$"](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA67).

Comment: @Peter That's also a way to prove, but the problem is to prove it by using the method of **CONTRADICTION**

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio So we are only allowed to use $q^2=-1$ ? In this case, I suggest that we conclude that this implies $q=-i$ or $q=i$ which contradicts the assumption that $q$ can be real ? Or isn't that "proof by contradiction" either ?

Comment: Is there any motivation to avoid to show $q^2\ge 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $q>0$ (obviously, $q\ne0$), then $q=\dfrac{-1}{q}<0$. Contradiction.

Similarly, suppose $q<0$, then $q=\dfrac{-1}{q}>0$. Contradiction.

Therefore, there are no such real numbers $q$ that $q^2=-1$.

Comment: You are halfway there.  Now suppose $q \lt 0 \ldots$

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem for me is understanding why this is a contradiction, why is "q = -1/q < 0" a contradiction?

Comment: Because you have supposed $q>0$ @dondeman

Comment: At first, we mention that $q>0$, however, $\dfrac{-1}{q}<0$, this makes a contradiction.